# Azure data factory merge files and set content type

Tags: azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-data-factory

I am using a SQL Server query which would return the last 3 months since a customer last purchased a product. For instance, There's a customer 100 that last made a purchase in August 2022. The SQL query will return June, July, August. Which would be in the format 062022, 072022, 082022. Now I need to be able to pass these values to the Copy data activity REST api dataset Relative URL (/salemonyr/062022) in the ForEach activity. So, I'm now able to store the json document per iteration but even though I use `Copy behavior-> Merge files` it runs over 3 iterations to over-write the files and not merge files with 3 months of data.

[image]

Also, I want the `content-type` to be `application/json`.

[image]

How would we be able to merge files and set the right content-type?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ForEach and looping through each iteration it will generate individual files. So, first step would be to copy those 3 files (don't use merge files feature here) to an intermediate location and once all three are copied, have a subsequent copy activity outside of ForEach, which will point source to the folder which has 3 files copied earlier and sink to your desired location and use merge files option which will generate a single data file. Then have a subsequent web activity and call [Set Blob Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-properties) API to update the content type property of the merged file.

[image]

Comment: Hi @KranthiPakala-MSFT, I'm using system assigned managed identity with self-hosted integration runtime and run into following error. `Error calling the endpoint 'https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net'. Response status code: 'ClientSideException : NameResolutionFailure'.  An error occurred while sending the request. 
Request didn't reach the server from the client. This could happen because of an underlying issue such as network connectivity, a DNS failure, a server certificate validation or a timeout. Exception message: 'The remote name could not be resolved`